# More video streams in a container

Tags: video, ffmpeg, formats

Many formats (containers) have an ability to host more video streams - e. g. MP4.

Is there a practical use of this advantage?

Comment: Multiple angles, multiple languages, video description, render-less editing...

Comment: @MichaelLiebman, it's not very convincing for me (maybe I don't fully understand). There may be 3 different files for 3 different languages - what is the advantage of having them all in 1 file? Similar for multiple angles. And I didn't imagine what is the render-less editing - how to make e. g. transitions without rendering?

Comment: On top of what @Michael Liebman said, having multiple streams in one container is in general for convenience. When you play a file in say VLC, you can change "angles" or said streams on the fly. There would be no need to open another file and remember timestamps to get to the same point of a video. The same with audio or subtitles.